# mysql_query does not save data properly

Tags: c++, mysql, utf-8

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mysql.h> 
#include <string> 
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std; 

MYSQL *connection, mysql; 
MYSQL_RES *result; 
MYSQL_ROW row; 
int query_state; 


int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{ 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
      mysql_init(&mysql);    
      mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx",0,0,0); 

  mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8"); 
  mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8' [COLLATE 'utf8_slovak_ci']"); 

  mysql_query(&mysql, "SELECT priezvisko FROM tour_pouzivatelia WHERE id_pouz=5"); 

  result = mysql_store_result(&mysql); 
  if ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL) {     
        string sql; 
        sql = "UPDATE tour_pouzivatelia SET priezvisko='"; 
        sql += row[0];
        sql += "' WHERE id_pouz=2";



        char* s = new char[sql.length()];


        strcpy(s, sql.c_str());

        mysql_query(&mysql, s); 
    } 


 getchar();
  return 0; 
}
```

The value in the database is `+ľščťžýáíéô§ň`, the tables have charset `utf8` and `ut8_slovak_ci` collation

Yet the following code saves the result as `+¾šèžýáíéúäô§ò`.

I'm using Visual studio 2010 c++ express.

The problem seems to be that `mysql_query` does not handle the sql passed to it, it removes the specific characters like š,č,ľ. I've tried many conversions, the function itself however requires the sql to be as `const char *`.

Is there any way to make this work, so that the `char *` variable will save the given characters correctly?

If I read the values from database they show up correctly...

Answer (score 3):

Before any DML, try to issue `SET names utf8` query (or other which you need)

Comment: Wow, that helped for the content from the database so that works now (though I'd swear I tried that before), nvm thanks:)

Comment: although it still does not work for sql = "UPDATE tour_pouzivatelia SET priezvisko='aľšč' WHERE id_pouz=1;"; it just saves the a alone, not the rest of the characters

Comment: Did you have hard coded the UPDATE query?Maybe file is not in UTF8 encoding.Try check if VS2010 encodes file in UTF8 (even if show ok) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696627/how-to-set-standard-encoding-in-visual-studio