# Change default Culture/Decimal localization

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-localization

I´m having a problem when trying to use a view Model that as a decimal property. Because my decimal **region/culture  format uses "," and not "." as decimal separator**.

When I try to post that model, I get the following error:

***The value xxx is not valid for the "field".***

I´m using jquery.unobstrusive and jquery.validation. So when I make the submit the model get validated and a error is shown an a label with the error above.

The thing is, the property does not have any kind of attributes (Required,Regex,Range). So that error is produced by the middleware/framework when trying to parse the string to decimal.

**If I type a decimal like: 40.05 the form submit with success.**

**If I type a decimal like: 40,05 the form submit fails with the above error.**

---

I have already read about Globalization at:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html#globalization-and-localization-terms

but could not find the "path" trought setting my globalization culture.
At MVC4/5 we were used to add a web.config tag at system.web and that's it. But at MVC6 that doesn´t seem to be the way.

Any tips?

Comment: These questions could give you some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513468/detect-decimal-separator
       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135569/how-to-change-symbol-for-decimal-point-in-double-tostring

Comment: to me it sounds like you are asking how to [configure the default culture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709060/how-to-change-the-default-culture)