# Working with UTF-8 std::string objects in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, encoding, utf-8

I'm using `Visual Studio` and `C++` on `Windows` to work with small caps text like `ʜᴇʟʟᴏ ꜱᴛᴀᴄᴋᴏᴠᴇʀꜰʟᴏᴡ` using e.g. [this](http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi) website. Whenever I read this text from a file or put this text directly into my source code using `std::string`, the text visualizer in `Visual Studio` shows it in the wrong encoding, presumably the visualizer uses `Windows (ANSI)`. How can I force `Visual Studio` to let me work with `UTF-8` strings properly?

```
std::string message_or_file_path = "...";
auto message = message_or_file_path;

// If the file path is valid, read from that file
if (GetFileAttributes(message_or_file_path.c_str()) != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES
    && GetLastError() != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
{
    std::ifstream file_stream(message_or_file_path);
    std::string text_file_contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_stream)),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    message = text_file_contents; // Displayed in wrong encoding
    message = "ʜᴇʟʟᴏ ꜱᴛᴀᴄᴋᴏᴠᴇʀꜰʟᴏᴡ"; // Displayed in wrong encoding
   std::wstring wide_message = L"ʜᴇʟʟᴏ ꜱᴛᴀᴄᴋᴏᴠᴇʀꜰʟᴏᴡ"; // Displayed in correct encoding
}
```

I tried the additional command line option `/utf-8` for compiling and setting the locale:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
std::cout.imbue(std::locale());
```

Neither of those fixed the encoding issue.

Comment: What is the encoding of the .cpp file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set standard encoding in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696627/how-to-set-standard-encoding-in-visual-studio)

Comment: You should open the `std::ifstream` in binary mode to avoid any data conversions while reading the `char`s. That will at least ensure the `std::string` has the correct bytes. That doesn't mean the *IDE* will display it correctly, though. Otherwise, use `std::wstring` instead, as you already discovered. You can read it with a `std::wifstream` that has a UTF-8 locale `imbue()`'ed into it. Or read the raw bytes first and then use `MultiByteToWideChar()` or `std::wstring_convert` to convert the bytes to `std:::wstring`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution was simply rewriting all `std::string`s as `std::wstring`s and adjusting the code logic properly to work with `std::wstring`s, as indicated in the question as well. Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

From [What’s Wrong with My UTF-8 Strings in Visual Studio?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/gdicanio/2016/11/22/whats-wrong-with-my-utf-8-strings-in-visual-studio/), there are a couple of ways to see the contents of a `std::string` with UTF-8 encoding.

Let's say you have a variable with the following initialization:

```
std::string s2 = "\x7a\xc3\x9f\xe6\xb0\xb4\xf0\x9f\x8d\x8c";
```

## Use a Watch window.

- Add the variable to Watch.
- In the Watch window, add `,s8` to the variable name to display its contents as UTF-8.

Here's what I see in Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

## Use the Command Window.

- In the Command Window, use `? &s2[0],s8` to display the text as UTF-8.

Here's what I see in Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

Comment: This may work for the text visualizer but it will not correct the code's encoding so it's only a semi solution. Still, you deserve your upvote.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza, what do you mean by the "the code's encoding"?

Comment: @R Sahu: I mean during processing of the code the string will not work correctly then. I e.g. copy the unicode text `std::string` object to the clipboard and when I paste it, it's screwed up. With a `std::wstring` version it works fine.