# Docfx Umlaute get not created in html

Tags: docfx

I'm creating documentation using DocFX. When I build and run the documentation on my Mac, everything works fine. However, when I run it on my Windows machine, it appears that my browser cannot handle German 'Umlaute' (äöü). It displays question marks instead. I haven't been able to find any documentation about this issue online. Has anyone else experienced the same problem and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue was that I created the individual files using Visual Studio, but I did not use the Unicode option. The following solved my problem: [How to set standard encoding in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696627/how-to-set-standard-encoding-in-visual-studio)