# How to set utf-8 encoding for files in Visual Studio for all new solutions

Tags: visual-studio, utf-8, codepages

I want to all my text files (.cs, .cpp, ...) in Visual Studio (2022) to UTF-8

There is one solution for this situation when data in file cannot be saved in default system codepage: [How to set standard encoding in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696627/how-to-set-standard-encoding-in-visual-studio). But my problem is data COULD be saved in default system codepage (my codepage is "Windows-1251"). But other software (for example GitHub) cannot always read sources in my system codepage and I get " Z̴̜̰̖҇̈́͜a҉̢̟̌͞ļ̴̱͇̓̂͋͠g̶̖҇́̍̓͜o̶̙̞̓̄́͜͝" " text. Therefore I seek the way to force VS save all text files in UTF-8 by default. I have no idea why the heck someone wants to save text data in codepage other then UTF-8.

The solution that I found is that I manually change the encoding of the file after it is created (see pictures).
[Windows-1251](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I812e.png)
[utf-8 (65001)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMECE.png)

Also I found [guide-solution for Windows](https://youtu.be/VCSPIoAWCT4?si=LWvfXTwplqneB2C1). The idea is to set UTF-8 to all Windows OS. This solves the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set standard encoding in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696627/how-to-set-standard-encoding-in-visual-studio)

Comment: In this thread they tried to do this but couldn't solve the problem. Only setting UTF-8 to all Windows OS solved the problem. But I would like a solution that affects only the IDE

Comment: That's not what that thread shows at all. Did you actually try the Options setting, or EditorConfig?

Comment: EditorConfig looks like a crutch

Comment: If you consider your editor's versionable settings a crutch, you won't be satisfied with *any* solution. Editorconfig guarantees that *all* members in a team can have the same settings. This will prevent someone else from saving their source code with a different encoding